# How to cleanup disk space on openshift when 'rhc tidy' has not enough disk space?

Tags: git, openshift, diskspace, openshift-client-tools

My quota on openshift has exceeded:

```
 Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
 /dev/mapper/EBSStore01-user_home01
            1048572       0 1048576            6890       0   80000
```

I found a different stackoverflow questions that the disk space can be cleaned by 'rhc app-tidy'

But when i run this command i get the following error:

```
Warning: Gear xxx is using 100.0% of disk quota
Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/xxx/mysql
```

When i run the following command do see which files are using the most space

```
du -h * | sort -rh | head -50
```

I get the following ouput:

```
605M    wildfly
320M    git/mythings.git/objects
320M    git/mythings.git
320M    git
317M    wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05
317M    wildfly/usr/lib/jvm
317M    wildfly/usr/lib
317M    wildfly/usr
166M    wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/jre
165M    wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib
136M    wildfly/versions/8
136M    wildfly/versions
118M    wildfly/versions/8/modules
118M    wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/lib
118M    wildfly/modules
116M    wildfly/versions/8/modules/system/layers/base
116M    wildfly/versions/8/modules/system/layers
116M    wildfly/versions/8/modules/system
116M    wildfly/modules/system/layers/base
116M    wildfly/modules/system/layers
116M    wildfly/modules/system
95M wildfly/versions/8/modules/system/layers/base/org
95M wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org
59M wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/i386
52M mysql/data
52M mysql
49M wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/lib/missioncontrol
43M wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/lib/missioncontrol/plugins
37M wildfly/versions/8/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss
37M wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss
32M wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/lib/visualvm
28M git/mythings.git/objects/76
26M wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/ext
26M git/mythings.git/objects/pack
26M git/mythings.git/objects/f6
21M wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/lib/visualvm/platform
21M app-root/runtime/repo
21M app-root/runtime
21M app-root
21M app-deployments/2014-08-04_14-34-47.614/repo
21M app-deployments/2014-08-04_14-34-47.614
21M app-deployments
20M wildfly/versions/8/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as
20M wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as
20M git/mythings.git/objects/ac
20M git/mythings.git/objects/8a
20M git/mythings.git/objects/6e
20M git/mythings.git/objects/69
20M git/mythings.git/objects/21
20M git/mythings.git/objects/12
```

As you can see the git directory takes a lot of space, but when i try to do 'git gc', i get the following error:

```
Counting objects: 226, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (192/192), done.
dm-0: write failed, user block limit reached.
fatal: sha1 file '/var/lib/openshift/xxx/git/mythings.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_ipHspL' write error: Disk quota exceeded
error: failed to run repack
```

So now i am out of ideas, what can i do to cleanup some space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Delete whatever you can easily restore from a backup or from a package, like e.g. the JDK. That should give you enough space to do cleanup.
Then restore whatever you deleted.

Or pay for more storage. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above you need to **ssh to your cartridge** (you will find code in web console - next to delete button) and then **cd to app-root/logs** and then run du -sh to check the dimension of the current dir, in my case the the file **php-error.log** was **542M**. You can safe delete it with **rm -f php-error.log**

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` to the application directory using `ssh clients (i use putty)` or `command prompt` then 
try to find out unnecessary files and delete them.

In my case deleting the content of `app-log` folder worked like charm.

**Give attention to temp and log folders**