# Openshift, disk quota exceeded

Tags: mysql, openshift, diskspace

After restarting application I get:

> Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge MySQL server failed to start:
>
> Error writing to temporary file cat:
>   /var/lib/openshift/.../app-root/logs//mysql.log:
>   No such file or directory
>
> Warning: Gear
>   ... is using 100.0% of disk quota
>
> Failed
>   to execute: 'control restart' for
>   /var/lib/openshift/.../mysql

Also I was trying to stop and start app from rhc commands. The app is not so big to realy fill all of the disk quota. Any advice how to resolve this?

App is working but https://app-name.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/ results in

> Service Temporarily Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to
>   service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems.
>   Please try again later.

Comment: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399760-Disk-Quota-Exceeded-Now-What-

Comment: after `rhc app-tidy java` -> Warning: Gear 54086a7c5973ca04190002e5 is using 100.0% of disk quota
Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/54086a7c5973ca04190002e5/mysql. 
App is quite small and that happened after some git pushes.

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley is there rhc command to download a database  copy from rhc? because it would be eaze to create a new app but I need a database copy...

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley app-root\logs is empty

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley here is list of largest folders:

`852M    git/java.git/objects
852M    git/java.git
852M    git
52M     mysql/data
52M     mysql
38M     app-root/runtime
38M     app-root
38M     app-deployments/2014-11-25_16-06-30.725
38M     app-deployments
36M     git/java.git/objects/c6
36M     git/java.git/objects/3f
34M     git/java.git/objects/ba
34M     git/java.git/objects/37
21M     jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF
21M     jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_
21M     jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost
21M     jbossews/work/Catalina
...`

which of them is safe to remove?

Comment: I read something about all previousle pushed data saved as reserved so maybe all that 852M is just history.

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley yes, I pushed ready wars but also my app is maven based and each time it uploads something there... that may be the reason for that. I know there is a way to push maven sources but still didn't learn how to work with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65693/discussion-between-jeremiah-winsley-and-andy).

Answer (score 2):

You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127219/how-to-cleanup-disk-space-on-openshift-when-rhc-tidy-has-not-enough-disk-space/27634573#27634573)

This usually happen when you app take almost all the space of the quota.

Check all log and temp folder and make the empty if not necessary.

To check how much you are using use `quota -s` after `ssh` to the app directory

Comment: This really helped me! Saved the day.

Comment: it is nice to know that it helped :) @stephenmurdoch

Answer (score 0):

also for me deleting the content of the app-log folder worked like charm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30788211)